# React Leaflet: Redefined method is not called

Tags: leaflet, react-leaflet

I am using react-leaflet to create my map. I need to fill a polygon with an image pattern. There is already a [plugin](https://github.com/bgx1012/leaflet-polygon-fillPattern-canvas) but it does not work with react-leaflet. So I am trying to write the plugin myself. The original plugin redefines the `_fillStroke` method of the `Canvas` class.

I tried to redefine the `_fillStroke` method myself.

```
import L from "leaflet";

L.Canvas.include({
  _fillStroke: (ctx: unknown, layer: unknown) => {
    console.log("Hello world")
  }
});
```

```
var poly1 = [
  [-124, 321],
  [-500, 321],
  [-500, 800],
  [-124, 321],
];
const poly = L.polygon(
  poly1 as [number, number][],
  { color: "red", opacity: 1, fillColor: "red", fillOpacity: 0.5, fill: true,  }
).addTo(mapInstance);
```

My guess was that if the method is correctly rewritten the polygon will not be displayed instead I will get a log output in the console. But polygon is rendered which means the method was not rewritten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it actually. Since it is not an npm package copy the js file into your local repo and import it directly. Then use `preferCancas` option of `MapContainer` and use an effect to initialize the polygon with the image background like this:

```
...
import fill from "./fill.gif";

function App() {
  const [map, setMap] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!map) return;

    var poly1 = [
      [24, 121],
      [24.5, 121],
      [25.5, 121],
      [25.5, 124],
      [24.5, 121.9],
      [24, 121.9]
    ];
    L.polygon(poly1, { imgId: "lamp" }).addTo(map);
  }, [map]);

  return (
    <>
      <img id="lamp" alt="no-lamp" style={{ display: "none" }} src={fill} />

      <MapContainer preferCanvas ref={setMap}>
      ...
     </MapContainer>

)
```

Make sure you import the img by giving a display none style and choose the path you would like to render

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-embed-leaflet-polygon-fillpattern-canvas-on-react-leaflet-v4-x-16r3qr?file=/src/App.js:351-771)